# Given a diagonal matrix, what is number of times $\lambda$ appears (on the diagonal)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose T ∈ L(V ) has a diagonal matrix A with respect to some basis of V and
that λ ∈ F. Prove that λ appears on the diagonal of A precisely dimE(λ, T) times.

Honestly, I have no clue how to prove this statement! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hint: $E(\lambda,T) = ker(T-\lambda id_V) \cong ker(A-\lambda\mathbb{1})$

Comment: @Simon I'm not sure how to use that...

Comment: $A-\lambda\mathbb{1}$ is a diagonal matrix ($\mathbb{1}$ is the identity-matrix). And for a diagonal matrix it should be easy to see that the dimension of the kernel is precisely the number of zeroes on the diagonal.

Comment: And the zeroes on the diagonal of $(A-\lambda\mathbb{1})$ correspond directly to the entries of $A$ which are equal to $\lambda$.

Comment: While the problem does not specify that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, you might take a look at Theorem 5.41 to get a sense of what the question entails. Then look at Ex. 5.37 and also consider the case when $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue - with the implication that $T-\lambda I$ in that instance is invertible and what that means for $\text{dim}E(\lambda,T)$.

Comment: I edited your header, do you see the difference from what you had previously?

Comment: @Simon thank you!! I figured it out!

Comment: Thank you to @TheBirdistheWord as well!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as Exercise 5.C.7 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Let $n:=\dim V$.
Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis with respect to which $T$ has $A$.
Let $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m\}$ be the set of elements of $\mathbb{F}$ which appear on the diagonal of $A$.
Then $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m\}$ is the set of the distinct eigenvalues of $T$ by 5.32 on p.152.
Assume that $\lambda_i$ appears on the diagonal of $A$ precisely $n_i$ times for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
Assume that $n_i\neq \dim E(\lambda_i,T)$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
Since $n_1+\dots+n_m=n$, there exists $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $n_j > \dim E(\lambda_j, T)$.
Since $\lambda_j$ appears on the diagonal of $A$ precisely $n_j$ times, there exists $v_{i_1},\dots,v_{i_{n_j}}\in\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ such that $i_k\neq i_l$ if $k\neq l$ and $Tv_{i_k}=\lambda_jv_{i_k}$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,n_j\}$.
So, $v_{i_1},\dots,v_{i_{n_j}}\in E(\lambda_j, T)$.
Since $v_{i_1},\dots,v_{i_{n_j}}$ is linearly independent, $\dim E(\lambda_j, T)\geq n_j>\dim E(\lambda_j, T)$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $n_i=\dim E(\lambda_i,T)$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$.
If $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda$ appears on the diagonal of $A$ precisely $0$ times by 5.32 on p.152.
And $\dim E(\lambda,T)=\dim \{0\}=0$.
If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda=\lambda_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
From the result above, $n_i=\dim E(\lambda_i,T)=\dim E(\lambda,T)$.
So, $\lambda$ appears on the diagonal of $A$ precisely $\dim E(\lambda,T)$ times.